# Pytorch - Should backward() function be in the loop of epoch or batch?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient

When training nn models using Pytorch, is there a difference regarding where we place the backward method? For example, which one of below is correct?

Calculate gradient across the batch:

```
for e in range(epochs):
    for i in batches_list:
        out = nn_model(i)
        loss = loss_function(out, actual)
        loss_sum += loss.item()
        lstm.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
loss_list.append(loss_sum / num_train_obs)
```

Calculate gradient across the epoch:

```
for e in range(epochs):
    for i in batches_list:
        out = nn_model(i)
        loss = loss_function(out, actual)
        loss_sum += loss.item()
    lstm.zero_grad()
    loss_sum.backward()
    optimizer.step()     
loss_list.append(loss_sum / num_train_obs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are programmatically correct.

The first one is batch gradient descent, and the second one is gradient descent. In most of the problems we want to do batch gradient descent, so the first one is the right approach. It is also likely to train faster.

You may use the second approach if you want to do Gradient descent (but it is seldom desired to do GD when you can do batch GD). However, since in GD you don't clear the graph every batch (`.zero_grad` is called only once), you may run out-of-memory.

Comment: So if the optimizer I use here is SGD, then the comparison becomes SGD vs SBGD, and I guess we usually would prefer SBGD over SGD?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to imply. SGD "algorithm" and SGD "optimizer" that pytorch has are different things.

Comment: @whj123 I think I understand your query better now. The comparison would be SBGD and GD. If batch size is 1, SBGD is SGD

Comment: right, SBGD and GD(since the second code is based on the entire data).